# Text Inserted into Listbox goes to the Bottom Instead of the Top

Tags: javascript, html, listbox

I am using javascript to add values from an input text to a listbox (select). For some reason, the text values inserted goes to the bottom instead of the top. How can I get it to start from the top please? Below is the code I'm using;

```
var i = 0;

function addValue() {
    var textValue = document.getElementById("txtValue");
    var v = textValue.value;
    AddOpt = new Option(v, v);
    document.getElementById("lstValues").options[i++] = AddOpt;
    v = "";
    return true;
}
```

Html Markup:

```html
<input id="txtValue" type="text" />
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" onclick="addValue();" />
<input id="btnRemove" type="button" value="Remove" onclick="deleteValue();" />
<br />
<select id="lstValues" multiple="multiple" style="width: 140px; height: 100px">
    <option value="empty"></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line

```
document.getElementById("lstValues").options[i++] = AddOpt;
```

with

```
document.getElementById("lstValues").add(AddOpt,0)
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b2q6un7p/)

Comment: Bingo! Just what I needed